# Who first studied semilattices?

Tags: abstract-algebra, math-history, lattice-orders, semigroups

Historically, who first studied semilattices, as opposed to lattices or Boolean algebras? (With or without identity, I do not mind.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears Grigore Moisil was first. Here's a review of his 1937 paper [*Recherches Sur le Principe d'Identite*](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=9087448&fileId=S0022481200039785).

The review says he studied them under the name of tautological groups. [This source](http://books.google.pl/books?id=27dkTJFrLZIC&pg=PA161&lpg=PA161&dq=klein%20halbverband#v=onepage&q=klein%20halbverband&f=false) says it was "logical groups", but it is less specific so I'm guessing the review is what's right. I don't have access to the actual paper. The book also mentions a Fritz Klein who introduced the term "Halbverband" in German, but that seems to have been in 1939 according to Clifford's footnote [here](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1968781?uid=2&uid=4&sid=21104616016423).